# Improve performance of this server code to look up domains?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, performance, optimization

We use Ruby to check domain availability, but the code runs painfully slow. We caching the Whois object across requests would accelerate performance, but other posts on SO suggest this would only marginally increase performance, if at all.

The code is so simple. We're not sure if other improvements could be made, or if we're just stuck with slow lookups because of the Whois object.

The **bulk_check** method accepts an array of domains to look up. Everything else is fairly self-explanatory.

We're on Rails 3.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

```
def bulk_check
    domains = params[:domains] || '[]'
    callback = params[:callback] || ''      
    results = []
    threads = []

    # String -> Array
    domains = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode domains

    # Iterate over each domain and spawn new thread to check domain status
    domains.each do |d|
      threads << Thread.new(d) { |my_domain|
        Thread.current['domain'] = my_domain
        Thread.current['status'] = get_domain_status my_domain
      }
    end

    # Wait for threads to finish and update results array
    threads.each do |t| 
        t.join
        results.push [ t['domain'], t['status'] ]
    end

    # Render results
    respond_to do |type|
        type.json { render :json => { :results => results }.to_json, :callback => callback }
    end
end


def get_domain_status domain
    begin
        # Create Whois object
        whois = Whois::Client.new

        # Query Whois for domain data
        result = whois.query domain

        # Prep JSON response
        status = result.available? ? 'available' : 'taken'
    rescue Exception => e
        puts "Exception in parsing '#{domain}' status: #{e.message}"
        status = 'error'
    end

    # Return status
    return status
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is not really a CPU intensive operation, but rather a "network intensive" - consider checking multiple domains simultaneously using Ruby threads or fibers.

For example, Celluloid gem makes it nice and easy: https://github.com/celluloid/celluloid/

Comment: Thanks! We forgot that Ruby was multi-threaded -- thought it was like JavaScript. We updated the question to show the new, multi-threaded version, but the code still seems to run sluggishly. Is there something we're doing wrong?

Comment: If you're using Ruby 1.8.7 (MRI) - it would only use one core, no matter how many threads you have. Also it's probably not the best idea to create a separate thread for each domain, if you have a ton of them. Consider "chunking" them into lesser number of threads, since each thread uses memory - you might be using too much of it.

Comment: BTW, JavaScript now has workers too - special kind of a thread. )

Comment: Thanks, Alex! When you say "too many," can you provide some guidelines? For instance, would spawning 50 threads at a time (i.e., checking 50 domains at once) be considered too much? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Alex, one last question: do you see anything wrong with the code? For some reason, the code fails if we issue multiple requests within milliseconds of each other -- though it only fails on the last request. An example: if we issue three requests where the first two contain 15 domains and the last one only contains 10 domains, the code consistently returns the "error" status for the last 10 domains (no matter what the domains).

Comment: I don't see any issues right away, just a guess: Whois::Client could be non-thread-safe.. Debugging multi-threaded applications is hard. Good luck.